# Opendkim v2.10 SenderHeaders correct syntax

Tags: syntax, email-headers, sender, dkim

So with version of Opendkim 2.10

SenderHeaders variable has been deprecated.

Check this posts [(1)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendkim/files/RELEASE_NOTES/view) and [(2)](http://sourceforge.net/p/opendkim/bugs/183/)

**Fix bug #183:** Discontinue support for ADSP. This removes the following configuration file items: SenderHeaders and others.

My long lasting Opendkim configuration falls apart as this fails even to start the service.

Always had this in my configuration:

```
SenderHeaders Sender,From
```

I need to sign emails if Sender header is there, so `d=` domain should be taken from Sender header if it is not set then use From. I use it to sign emails for clients "`On behalf`" seen in major ISPs' as "`via domain.com`"

What is Sender header, what I found was best explained in [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14253556/4793739):

Suggestions how to solve it?

By the way I have couple of domains I use, so wildcard option to sign all emails tied to one entry in KeyTable/domain is not acceptable for my configuration.

--

** Edit (2015-04-20)

I managed to get an answer from developers. Here it is:

> You would use the Lua hooks to do this now.  The man page for
>   opendkim-lua(3) should have the information you need to set this up,
>   but basically you would write a script that pulls out the Sender
>   header field, then makes a signing request based on what's in there. 
>   This would need to be referenced as the "setup" Lua script.  So:
>
> sender = odkim.get_header(ctx, "Sender", 0) [whatever logic you want
>   here, then] odkim.sign(ctx, name-of-key-to-use)
>
> The "name-of-key-to-use" is expected to be a name that appears in your
>   KeyTable.
>
> -MSK

Comment: Hi @Arnoldas, did you found a solution for that case? Did you manage to get a LUA script running?

Comment: Hi @scube I asked in opendkim channel at sourceforge how do I continue using it, so it was reverted back in version 2.10.2 so check it out http://sourceforge.net/projects/opendkim/files/RELEASE_NOTES/view

As for Lua script sorry I don't know the language.