# Amazon SES adding random number in email header

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses

I'm using Amazon SES for email server, and set the header information from PHP code.

The from value is set correctly in the email header, but SES adds a different random number in "Return-Path:" and "Message-ID: "

```
Message-ID: <000001524603fa28-f2221670-bc0b-4ab7-b5ae-3bd68ed8ea24-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>

Return-Path: <000001524603fa28-f2221670-bc0b-4ab7-b5ae-3bd68ed8ea24-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
```

The from value that is set in PHP:
From no-reply@myweb.com Fri Jan 15 16:00:11 2016

All the emails are going out ok, but some receivers are blocking them with a rule set for that amazonses value

Is there a way to set that value in Amazon SES? I've been looking for days in their documentation and forums and nothing came out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those values are with regards to SES's antispam mechanisms. They are implemented so that an out going message can be tracked back and reported as spam to the SES servers.

[Message-ID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-ID) is a globally unique identifer that uniquely identifies the message (against every other email ever sent)

[Return-path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367358/whats-the-difference-between-sender-from-and-return-path) tells the client where reports concerning non-delivery can be sent.

The mix of these two headers means that SES know the reasons that messages are returned and can give you opportunity to deal with them. This is done in order to keep them off blacklists.

The only way that you could remove these headers would be to switch mail senders.

Considering the breadth of businesses that use SES it surprises me that it is blocked as a sender. That would surely mean a lot of missing messages.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this specific business is blocking all emails that comes from SES, they said they get too much spam? so the email is being blocked intentionally in their servers

Comment: @LauraCáceres In that case it comes down to the value of having a line of communication with that business. If it is your primary income source then you should consider moving away from SES. Depending on what you have sending messages to SES you might be able to reroute what messages are sent to that company.