# Avoiding email filters with legitimate use of spoofing

Tags: email

I have a web application that will be used by committee chairs to communicate with committee members over email.  All these users will have e-mail accounts external to the web application and domain the web application is hosted on.  Any replies from members need to be directed to the e-mail of the committee chair user, not an account on the domain of the web application.  The only two methods of accomplishing this that I've come up with are

1. In the from of the e-mail, use the e-mail of the sending user.  E-mail applications for many of the committee members block this as spam.
2. Use an account such as no-reply@applicationdomain.com, and then include instructions in the e-mail of the correct address that replies should be sent to.  Users often get confused and don't send replies to the correct address.

Are there any alternatives I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, this was the purpose of the `Sender` email header. If you want an email to be `From` the user, but sent by you, you would just set the `Sender` header to an email address on your domain but have `From` be the user. Also, the SMTP envelope sender should also be on your domain. Then, you would be properly declaring that you're the sender of the message for anti-spam purposes, you'll receive any bounce messages, but email clients will know that the email is reportedly from the "real" user, and will direct replies accordingly. Generally, email clients would report both Sender and From, saying something like "From my-server@website.example.net on behalf of real-user@example.com", though obviously the details depend on the email client being used.

Refer to [What's the difference between Sender, From and Return-Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4367358/65839) and [OpenSPF Web Generated Email Best Practices](http://www.openspf.org/Best_Practices/Webgenerated) for more information.

However, now [DMARC](https://dmarc.org/) has come along. It has made the decision that verification should be based only on the `From` header. The theory is that there's no way for an end-user to know whether a particular `Sender` is in fact authorized to send mail "on behalf of" the user listed in the `From` header. While it probably isn't the decision I would have made due to how it ignores the traditional `Sender`, it's something that needs to be dealt with now, as if the domain of the user listed in the `From` has a DMARC record that is set to `q=reject`, then nobody else, including your web form that's trying to send mail with the complete approval of the user, can send mail that's `From` that domain. More and more domains are turning on DMARC, and as they do so your form won't be able to send email `From` them, regardless of what other headers are set.

The only other alternative, then, is to have email be `From` your application entirely, but set the `Reply-To` header to where the email program should send replies to. Also, the SMTP envelope sender should be your application, and ideally be set to an address that can handle bounce messages or other errors. You shouldn't need to include any instructions, as the `Reply-To` header is very well supported among email clients as indicating where replies should be directed.

Refer to the DMARC FAQ entry "[Why are messages I send on behalf of visitors to my website being blocked?](https://dmarc.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_are_messages_I_send_on_behalf_of_visitors_to_my_website_being_blocked.3F)".