# How to set mail header for Contact Form web page

Tags: email, contact-form-7, spam-prevention, email-headers

I have to make something like a contact form to send email from a website. In the form fields there are the sender mail address and is where the receiver reply to.

How should I set mail headers to be compliant to most antispan and to let the received use the reply button of his mail client?

I read this post [What's the difference between Sender, From and Return-Path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367358/whats-the-difference-between-sender-from-and-return-path)
But I did not understand what is the right setting for this case.

Usually I used the `From:` field but this resulted a spoofed mail and many antispam delete them (obiousbly my site MTA is not on contacts SPF).